# Clojure - ajax.core POST

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am having some trouble with POST from ajax.

I want to add a user to my database, so I am using POST and the data I want to send is in the form `{:id id :pass pass}` This is my POST

`(defn add-user! [user] 
  (POST "/add-user!"
   {:params user}))`

All I want to do is enter information in the form specified above into this POST so I can send it to the database. I know that the argument,to the POST, is in the right form and the queries to the database and my routes are correct but I've made a mistake with the POST and I cannot figure out my mistake.

I am calling `add-user!` by

```
(defonce fields (atom {}))


(defn add-user! [user]
  (POST "/add-user!"
       {:params user}))



(defn content
  []
  [:div
   [:div
    [:p "Enter Name:"
     [:input
      {:type      :text
       :name      :name
       :on-change #(swap! fields assoc :id (-> % .-target .-value))
       :value     (:id @fields)}]]
    [:p "Enter Pass:"
     [:input
      {:type      :text
       :name      :pass
       :on-change #(swap! fields assoc :pass (-> % .-target .-value))
       :value     (:pass @fields)}]]
    [:input
     {:type     :submit
      :on-click #(do
                  (add-user! @fields))
      :value    "Enter"}]]
   [:div
    [:p "Id is " (:id @fields)]
    [:p "Pass is " (:pass @fields)]]])
```

My query to the database in a clj file is

```
(defn add-user! [user]
  (sql/insert! db :users user))
```

where sql is `[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]`

Comment: You've said what you think you know is correct, but you've not given any examples of how you're calling `add-user!`, and you've not confirmed whether or not you can manually do a POST with a URL, and given an example of a working POST and its URL.  Doing this, and including this information, would give something to go on.  Otherwise, you're asking readers to play the guessing game, which is what it seems like you've done, and that's not an effective approach to solving problems, generally speaking.

Comment: Is this what you meant or did you want to see the compojure routes as well? @Josh

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: It's not adding a user to the database. If I try to add a user, when I check the database I can see that a new user hasn't been added

Comment: Is there an HTTP request being done to the `/add-user` endpoint when you click the `submit` button? If so, have you created the correct routes in your server? Have you tried just printing or logging something in the server side `add-user!` function to make sure it is being called?

Comment: The is a HTTP request being done which is a POST which is good, however I am getting an Error 500. I added some println statements and the argument being sent to my route (on the server) is not correct, it is an error. I think I have done the POST add-user! function incorrectly as it is not sending the correct argument

Comment: You can use chrome/firefox dev tools to see if the data is being sent properly. If it is sent properly then the bug is on the server side. Do you have any server side logs of the error?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really enough information here to help you debug this fully, but I suspect that you need to modify your `POST` to:

```
(defn add-user! [user] 
  (POST "/add-user!"
    {:format :json
     :params user}))
```

If you don't provide `:format`, cljs-ajax defaults to sending Transit data, which would definitely confuse a server expecting JSON.

> `:format` - specifies the format for the body of the request (Transit, JSON, etc.). Also sets the appropriate Content-Type header. Defaults to `:transit` if not provided. - [JulianBirch/cljs-ajax#getpostput](https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax#getpostput)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me with this code:

```
 (POST "/admin/tests/load"
    {:params {:test-id "83"}
     :headers {"x-csrf-token" csrf-field}
     :handler (fn [r] (do (.log js/console r) (swap! test-state r)))
     :format :json
     :response-format :json
     :error-handler (fn [r] (prn r))})))
```

"params" always showed up empty "{}". Then I tried:

```
 (POST "/admin/tests/load"
    {:params {:test-id "83"}
     :headers {"x-csrf-token" csrf-field}} )
```

and all started working well, even after adding the other options. I know, weird.